# Where to find references added to Roslyn's Session?

Tags: c#, shell, console, roslyn

I'm trying to code a console shell using `Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp`. Of course user is able to dynamically add references to the `Session` using methods of host object:

```
public void AddRef(string nameOrPath)
{
    session.AddReference(nameOrPath);
}

public void AddRef(System.Reflection.Assembly asm)
{
    session.AddReference(asm);
}
```

But I also want him to be able to list already loaded assemblies. How to do that?

Not working / bad solutions:

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` - yields all assemblies loaded to the AppDomain which are not necessarily avaible in Roslyn's scripting session
- Using `ScriptEngine`'s property `GetReferences()` - as I've understood, it returns session-wide list of references, and my `AddRef` method doesn't change it
- Collecting own list of added references. But what if reference was added by display name? How to convert `string nameOrPath` to `Assembly` type? Using `Roslyn.Compilers.MetadataReference` does not help, because it hasn't got the reference to `Assembly`.